# Using Salesforce mobile SDK how do I call an Apex REST endpoint?

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, mobilesdk

In my scratchorg I've got:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Test/')
global without sharing class RestTest {
    @HttpGet
    global static String test() {
        return 'cat';
    }
}
```

And in workbench I've tested this by calling `GET` on `/services/apexrest/namespace/Test/` and it returns successfully.

So now I want to call this same end point from the mobile sdk. Presumably using the `net.sendRequest` method from react-native-force.

But I'm not exactly sure on how to use it. I've got `sendRequest('/services/apexrest/namespace/Test/', '', resolve, reject, 'GET');` Which I think? is correct. but I'm not sure on what should be in the 2nd parameter (path).

I've also tried variations such as:

`sendRequest('/services/apexrest', '/namespace/Test/', resolve, reject, 'GET');`

I've also tried:

```
    net.sendRequest(
        ...
        'GET',
        undefined,//payload
        undefined,//header
        undefined,//fileparams
        undefined,//returnbinary
        false//not requires auth
    );
```

Comment: What kind of mobile app are you building? I'm assuming hybrid given your code sample?

Comment: @MattLacey yep react native for both ios and android

Comment: @KrisGoncalves thanks for your input, unfortunately adding the api version does not work (with and without slash). I still get the same "URL no longer exists" error